# How to exactly replicate the behaviour of Windows cmd shell mkdir with Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, mkdir

I am trying to find a way to programmatically create folders on my PC, which selectively sync through "Ignore files with these extensions" filter to my Google Drive storage with Back Up And Sync app.

Context:

I run a file server which I'm trying to make accessible through the Google Drive. But, there are some folders which I would like to filter out and the way I create folders seems to affect the sync process.

So, on the server, I have ".workspace" folders with large Temp files, which I do not wish to sync. To achieve such behavior, I am using "Ignore files with these extensions" filter. So, inside Back Up and Sync I've added ".workspace" extension to the ignore list.

When I create my ".workspace" folder with Windows CMD shell mkdir function - my folder exhibits the correct and expected behavior and does not sync to my GoogleDrive cloud storage.

But, when I create my ".workspace" folder with Python os functions - my folder exhibits the incorrect and different behavior and gets uploaded to my GoogleDrive cloud storage.

Here are the functions

```py
import os
dirName = ".workspace"
os.mkdir(dirName)
```

OR

```
os.makedirs(dirName)
```

This leads me to believe that the internal processes of folder creation in Python is similar to using Windows Explorer as the same problem happens when creating folders manually.

My goal is to find a Python function to create folders in Window's native CMD way.

Do you have any pointers or are there any lower level python modules that I should be using instead of the OS module?

Comment: you can always perform a system call `os.system("mkdir .workspace")`

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for the correction. Fixed! I know how extremely important it is to be consistent and I tried very very very hard, yet here we are. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `os` module is the direct interface to the operating system. So `mkdir` calls the Windows `mkdir` function, which is not the "native" windows function (which is [`CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya)) but rather the POSIX version.

That doesn't mean that the historical `mkdir` function does exactly the same thing. It probably calls `CreateDirectory` directly.

I wouldn't normally recommend to perform a system call for such basic tasks, and even less recommend to use `shell=True`, but in your special case, since it's the only thing that works for you, you could call `mkdir` command with a system call from python

```
import subprocess
# now call built-in mkdir command from Windows cmd
subprocess.check_call(r"mkdir .workspace",shell=True)
```

Using `shell=True` as `mkdir` is built-in, without it the command would not be found as there is no `mkdir.exe`

Comment: CPython's [implementation of `os.mkdir`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L2663) with a byte string (should be using `unicode` for files in Windows) just calls `CreateDirectoryA(path, NULL)`. If we step through CMD's implementation of `mkdir` in `cmd!MdWork` we see that it simply calls `CreateDirectoryW`. There's nothing special here -- not unless something is hooking `CreateDirectoryW` in the system via DLL injection or a filter driver at a lower level.

Comment: I obviously could not test what OP says, but I tried to provide 2 implementations of the most raw/native way. Took me a few minutes to add a win32 API answer that works.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I'll try this out and post back with an update!